# Publish flash player in user wall does not work?

Tags: php, flash, facebook, publish

Hi first i want to clarify that this is not a question about how to embed a flash player in user wall, because i already know how to do it.

The question is if anybody can help me whith my code or if someone has the same problem as me and it is a bug.

I want to publish this link ( http://www.test.hollybyte.tv/watch/4e45080a94a05f1478000000 ) into wall via Graph Api. If you see the code of the link you can see that the required metas are wrote. In fact, if you paste the link in Fb, you can see that it recognise and even publish the player.

For test purpose i have used the Graph API Explorer ( http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) with this parameters:

- Method: "POST"
- Api : https://graph.facebook.com/user/feed
- oauth_token : ...
- message: "Test from API Explorer"
- link: http://www.test.hollybyte.tv/watch/4e45080a94a05f1478000000
- picture: http://repo.eu-w1.hollybyte.com/acc/test/as/4e45080a94a05f1478000000/splash.jpg
- source: http://repo.eu-w1.hollybyte.com/acc/test/py/default-flash/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf?config=http://repo.eu-w1.hollybyte.com/acc/test/st/www/default/js/emb/4e45080a94a05f1478000000.js
- type: video

And it does post perfectly well, wiht the player !!

But when i tried the same thing wiht PHP using Facebook PHP SDK, it does not. It publish a link but with no picture, nor player either.

My PHP code for this is:

```
$facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => $this->_appId, 'secret' => $this->_appSecret));
$param = array(...); //Array with all the data from above, the same data.
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$userId.'/feed', 'post', $param);
echo $result;
```

I do not understand why, whith the API Explorer works fine, but whit my PHP call does not. Please tell me if it is a bug, or what i am doing wrong.

I have to say that i have all permissions right (publish stream, offline access, read stream), and i can post to wall so it is not a permission problem (or correcti if i am wrong)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

P.D.
I am not used to write in english, so forgive me if i have some grammar errors.

Comment: do you get an error message? What is the contents of the $result variable after the call to facebook?

Comment: @Lix I do not get any error. The content of $result is: `( [id] => 100001096238224_240580642655142 )` Like when i publish something else on the wall.

Comment: well.. that's the facebook object id... it means that the post was made successfully... It looks like your code is correct but you have a problem with your parameters. are you sure that the url's to the picture and source are correct?

Comment: @Lix Yes, there are all ok. If you follow the link of each link, you can see for yourself, they all have something and are correct. And i am sure that i send the correct parameters because before send them, i log them, and they are all ok.
I do not understand really, maybe is a bug for graph API (i do not think so because API Explorer publish correctly). For your experience, Lix, what do you think what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Feed dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), It doesnt look like there is supposed to be a `type` parameter in the param array... In addition, the `message` parameter should not be used - facebook said that they will start ignoring that parameter from July 12 :

> "This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011"

They also say things like

> The URL of a media file (e.g., a SWF or video file) attached to this post. If both source and picture are specified, only source is used.

You should try removing unnecessary parameters. I dont believe that there is a bug with the API... Most of the times when I have encountered these types of bugs it was an issue of wrong parameters.

Comment: Thanks but you link me to javascript example, and i am using php. The documentation i am follow is this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/. I will remove parameters and let you know.

Comment: The first part of the page IS a javascript example - but if you scroll down a little you will see that the documentation does not limit you to one SDK - the parameters are the same in javascript, in php and in any other SDK...

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/brent/feed?
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&


  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!`

All you have to do is use `cURL` or `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Ok I see now. But that is to open a dialog, and i do not want that. And the code you posted is the equivalent for a graph API Post. I remove source parameter and it show the image. I will keep on try & error whith parameters and let you know.

Comment: Finnally I made it !! I just need to use **message**, **link** and **type**. ONLY !! I hope that some day Fb will update his documentation Monthly (at least). Thank you Lix for your help.

Comment: if you look further down on that link you'll see a section titled `Publishing` there u will find how to use http POST methods to publish  stories to users feeds using ONLY the API, no dialogs...
`You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs, using an access token.`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the solution.

If you want to publish a link to a flash player in user wall. You only need tree paremeters

- **Message**: The message you want (optional).
- **Link**: A link to the page with the player. The page must have the proper metas (video_src, video_img, etc...)
- **Type**: Video.

And only those parameters, no more.

Thanks Lix to show me the way.

Comment: It doesn't take out og tags that way. Don't know why. Do you know how to force it?

Answer (score 0):

Tolke does your embed still work ? It seems that Flash ,Video Embed is not working anymore mostly all over FB. Two exceptions youtube and vimeo serving over https .
dont get it to work with the usual parameter